# What's the difference between collective classification and semi-supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I encountered the trouble like the title:
The definition of collective classification is "Collective classification is the area in machine learning, in which unknown nodes in the network are classified based on the classes assigned to the known nodes and the network structure only."
Semi-supervised learning is to infer the correct labels for the given unlabeled data ---wiki

Thus the only diff between them is that cc has classification while ssl doesn't. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Semi supervised learning**  is more general - it does not specify/stipulate the structure of the input data.  It can be summarized as "learning from a combination of  labeled and unlabeled data points".  The **approach** to performing the inference is also unspecified.

The "Collective classification" as you have reflected above ***does*** specify the way in which the unlabeled points are inferred:

> based on the classes assigned to the known nodes and the network
>   structure only.

So there is an additional expectation on the data that they are
- represented in a graph structure
- their correlation can be used to computer their relative similarity and hence their class

A summary of Collective Classification from this paper https://www.cs.uic.edu/~xkong/sdm11_icml.pdf helps to illustrate the (higher) expectations on the data structure and semantics:

> Collective classification in relational data has become animportant and
>   active research topic in the last decade,where class labels for a
>   group of linked instances are cor-related and need to be predicted
>   simultaneously.

The note about the **types** of problems applicable is also revealing - notice they are graph oriented data analysis tasks:

> Collective classification has a wide variety of real
>   world appli-cations,e.g.hyperlinked document classification,
>   socialnetworks analysis and collaboration networks analysis